# Need to change the date format by using tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

def problem3_3(month, day, year):

```
months = ('January','February','March','April','May',"June",'July','August', 
          'September','October','November','December')
new_date = months[5] + " " + str(day), str(year)

print(new_date)
```

The output is 
('June 17', '2016') instead of June 17 , 2016
how do i remove these commas 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The comma should be an string also, try something like this

```
months = ('January','February','March','April','May',"June",'July','August', 
          'September','October','November','December')
new_date = months[5] + " " + str(day)+','+ str(year)

print(new_date)
```